# In which locations are Azure Large Instances (for SAP HANA) available?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, sap-hana

[As per this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/virtual-machines/sap-hana/), some of the Azure Large Instance VMs are available only in US East. In which US & European locations are these available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently available in the following regions:

- East us
- West us
- North Europe
- West Europe
- Australia East
- Australia Southeast

SAP HANA on Azure (Large Instances): Official name for the offer in Azure to run HANA instances in on SAP HANA TDI certified hardware that is deployed in Large Instance stamps in different Azure regions

Reference:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/regions/services/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/sap/hana-overview-architecture?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json#definitions

Comment: I'm assuming "SAP HANA on Azure Large Instances" means M & S series VMs as per this link- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/sap-hana/ While the link you shared shows "SAP HANA on Azure Large Instances" are available in the regions specified, the same link also shows M series VMs which are used for SAP workloads are available only in limited regions matching info here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/sap-hana/  What exact VM types does "SAP HANA on Azure Large Instances" refer to?

Comment: This article that was last updated on 2016-12-1 seems to say only S series VMs are referred as Azure Large Instances for SAP HANA -
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/sap/hana-overview-architecture?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json

Comment: Yes, the so called M & S series are the Large Instances as they call. SAP HANA on Azure (Large Instances) is the official name for the offer in Azure to run HANA instances in on SAP HANA TDI certified hardware that is deployed in Large Instance stamps in different Azure regions.

Comment: So for better clarity this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/regions/services/ should call out what is in "SAP HANA on Azure Large Instances" as it is possibly referring only to S series VMs